# Reload hotkey in genymotion

Tags: genymotion

in android emulator it's possible to reload an app with pressing the `r` key twice.

What's the equivalent in Genymotion?

`Ctrl + M` opens the dev menu, but it's cumbersome to use it for reloading.

Also the reload shortcut doesn't appear in the [official docs](https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/02_Application/Genymotion_shortcuts.htm). Am I missing something?

Comment: Would love a reload shortcut too. Didn't know about ctrl + m, that will help a lot

Comment: Just noticed you've already provided the same answer in your question. Double tapping R doesn't work for you ?

Answer (score 5):

If you tap the `R` key twice in quick succession, it will reload the app.